# React this.SetState is undefined - nested function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Making my first react app. I want to update the google maps api based on the user's location. 
I am receiving the error "this is undefined". I understand using .bind(this) and wrapping in an arrow function but think this case is a bit different because I am setting state inside a nested function:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {zip: null, lat: 40.5304 , lng: -100.6534 , zoom: 3.8 };

    this.updateCurrentPosition= this.updateCurrentPosition.bind(this);
  }
  
  //...
  
updateCurrentPosition = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    
      function success(pos) {
        this.setState(`{lat: ${pos.coords.latitude}, lng: ${pos.coords.longitude}, zoom: ${3.8}`)  
      }
    
      function error(err) {
        console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
      }; 
  }

  ops = () => { 
    return {
      center: { lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng },
      zoom: this.state.zoom
    }
  };
```

Comment: `I understand using .bind(this) and wrapping in an arrow function but think this case is a bit different because I am setting state inside a nested function:` No its not. Use `bind` or a arrow function.

Comment: Wrapping the success callback as an arrow function returns a type error from the geolocation api because Argument 1 of Geolocation.getCurrentPosition is not an object

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions automatically bind functions to the parent class. If a function is not binded, or not an arrow function, "this" will refer only to the function itself, even if it is nested. Your success function (and failure function too) is not bound to the parent class, as you have neither binded it or defined it as an arrow function.

Comment: I changed the success function into an arrow function however the geolocation.getCurrentPosition method complained the first argument (this.success) was not an object. binding this.success = this.success.bind(this) returns "this.success is not defined"
I'm not seeing something!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this` is undefined under strict mode in Javascript. You can refer to this paragraph to read more http://2ality.com/2014/05/this.html

For your particular question, when you defined `success` and `error`, the two functions are not bound to parents.

The following modification by defining the functions as arrow functions will resolve your issue.

```
const success = (pos) => {
    this.setState(`{lat: ${pos.coords.latitude}, lng: ${pos.coords.longitude}, zoom: ${3.8}`)
}

const error = (err) => {
    console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It looks like the geolocation api return a type error "Argument 1 of Geolocation.getCurrentPosition is not an object."

Comment: Did you call `getCurrentPosition ` after you declared `success` and `error`? It should work if you called after you declared the methods.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've instead passed the functions directly as arguments to the getCurrentPosition method and it seems to work fine.

```js
updateCurrentPosition = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (pos) => {
        this.setState({ lat: pos.coords.latitude, lng: pos.coords.longitude, zoom: 1 }) 
      },
      (err) => {
        console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`)
      }
    )
  }
```